# Trying to fix a hurdle formula that's not working past a certain hurdle

Tags: microsoft-excel

Here are the two formulas I've tried:

```
=IF(B13<600000,B13*3%,IF(B13>600000,600000*3%+(B13-600000)*4%,IF(B13<1000000,B13*4%,IF(B13>1000000,1000000*4%+(B13-1000000)*5%,IF(B13<1500000,B13*5%,IF(B13>1500000,1500000*5%+(B13-1500000)*6%))))))

=IF(B13<600000,B13*3%,IF(B13>600000,600000*3%+(B13-600000)*4%,IF(B13>1000000,600000*3%+(400000*4%)+(B13-1000000)*5%,IF(B13>1500000,600000*3%+(400000*4%)+(500000*5%)+(B13-1500000)*6%))))
```

This is the information I'm using to get the numbers that aren't equalling the correct number.

```
Jan 117,223         
Feb 115,340         
Mar 126,307         
Apr             
May             
Jun             
Jul             
Aug             
Sep 641500          
Oct             
Nov             
Dec             
TOTAL   1000370         




  600,000   3%          
1,000,000   4%          
1,500,000   5%
```

34014.8 <- should be $34,019

Everything is good until 1 million but after 1 million it's not calculating at 5%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should do the trick:

```
=IF(B13<=600000,B13*3%,IF(B13<=1000000,600000*3%+((1000000-600000)-(1000000-B13))*4%,IF(B13<=1500000,600000*3%+(1000000-600000)*4%+((1500000-1000000)-(1500000-B13))*5%,600000*3%+(1000000-600000)*4%+(1500000-1000000)*5%+(B13-1500000)*6%)))
```

The result I get is **$34018.50**.

Breaking down the formula:

- If the total is less than or equal to $600,000, the figure is 3% of the total.
- Otherwise if the total is less than or equal to $1,000,000, the figure is 3% of $600,000 + 4% of however many dollars above $600,000 up to $1,000,000.
- Otherwise if the total is less than or equal to $1,500,000, the figure is 3% of $600,000 + 4% of however many dollars above $600,000 up to $1,000,000 + 5% of however many dollars above $1,000,000 up to $1,500,000.
- Otherwise if the total is greater than $1,500,000, the figure is 3% of $600,000 + 4% of however many dollars above $600,000 up to $1,000,000 + 5% of however many dollars above $1,000,000 up to $1,500,000 + 6% of however many dollars above $1,500,000.

Comment: Oh my goodness!!!!!! You ROCK!!! This worked and you have save my poor computer from being thrown out the office door!!!! THANK YOU SOOOOOOOOOOOOO much!!! You ARE brilliant and I truly appreciate you taking the time to answer my question!!!!!!!!!!